# Problems using uri on axios

Tags: reactjs, request, axios, cors, uri

I currently work with an api rest where I pass the controller parameters, version and action via URI. However, when I execute a request with URI with more than 19 characters, it gives this CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-api-host/toll/vehicle/v1/list' from origin 'http://localhost: 3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

In authentication the request works even with URI having more than 19 characters. However, any other request with a different URI that has more than 19 characters gives this same error. I use my application's API and the request works normally.

I'm using axios in Reactjs.
The api is already configuring to accept the content-type I am using (application / json) and is also already accepting requests from different sources.

My request code:

```
request(uri, params = {}){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
                .post('http://my-api-host' + uri, JSON.stringify(params), {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.success) {
                        resolve(response.data);
                    } else {
                        reject(response.data);
                    }
                });
        });
    };
```

**Has anyone been through this and could help? thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Fetch instead?

```
async function postData(url = '', params = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    qs: JSON.stringify(params) // query string data
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('http://my-api-host', params)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: what is strange is that if I print some data in my API, the request returns 200 and I capture that data that I print. And after I do that it works all the requests that were giving this error before, then I print some data again in the api and it works again. Weird is not it?

Comment: Weird can you share your api also Enabling CORS in the API

Comment: In my api conteins this config:



    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1800"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
 Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"

Comment: I run another teste, and what is strange is that if I print some data in my API, the request returns 200 and I capture that data that I print. And after I do that it works all the requests that were giving this error before, then I print some data again in the api and it works again. Weird is not it?

Comment: I solved
the problem was that my API accepted requests but was not handling OPTIONS requests correctly and did not respond with code 200.

Solution:

I applied a comparison for when the REQUEST_METHOD is OPTIONS in addition to accepting to respond with code 200.

Comment: great Nathan many times it depends on the API settings to know if everything should work as expected